# как выровнять span'ы после иконки awesome

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, fontawesome

У разных иконок - разная ширина. И из-за этого разбивается начало текста. Как выровнять?

[image: пикча]

```
<li><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i><span class="ml-2">для ипотеки - от 4500руб.</span></span></li>
<li><span><i class="far fa-balance-scale"></i><span class="ml-2">для суда - от 7000руб.</span></span></li>
<li><span><i class="fas fa-handshake"></i><span class="ml-2">для продажи - от 4000руб.</span></span></li>
<li><span><i class="fas fa-gavel"></i><span class="ml-2">для наследства - от 4000руб.</span></span></li>
```

Comment: сделать 2 колонки | 1- иконки | 2 - текст

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться классом [fa-fw](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/fixed-width-icons)

```css
ul{
  padding-left: 0;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
    <li>
        <i class="fas fa-home fa-fw"></i>
        <span class="ml-2">для ипотеки - от 4500руб.</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <i class="fas fa-balance-scale fa-fw"></i>
        <span class="ml-2">для суда - от 7000руб.</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <i class="fas fa-handshake fa-fw"></i>
        <span class="ml-2">для продажи - от 4000руб.</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <i class="fas fa-gavel fa-fw"></i>
        <span class="ml-2">для наследства - от 4000руб.</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Это просто ох***но!

Comment: @soledar10 хороший, полезный ответ (+)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `min-width`...

```css
.fas {
  min-width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<li><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i><span class="ml-2">для ипотеки - от 4500руб.</span></span>
</li>
<li><span><i class="fas fa-balance-scale"></i><span class="ml-2">для суда - от 7000руб.</span></span>
</li>
<li><span><i class="fas fa-handshake"></i><span class="ml-2">для продажи - от 4000руб.</span></span>
</li>
<li><span><i class="fas fa-gavel"></i><span class="ml-2">для наследства - от 4000руб.</span></span>
</li>
```

P.S. У Вас опечатка во второй строке `far` -> `fas`